# Lazy load the ng-content of an Angular component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-template

I created a Tabs component used as follows ([Online example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulartabs))

```
<tabs>
  <tab title="tab 1" active="true">Content 1</tab>
  <tab title="tab 2">Content 2</tab>
</tabs>
```

The Tabs Component HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="head">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="select(tab)" class="tab" [class.active]="tab.active">
      <a>{{ tab.title }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

How to lazy load each Tab content (load it when the Tab becomes active)?

The Tabs component code is:

```
export class TabsComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>;

  select(tab: TabComponent) {
    this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);
    tab.active = true;
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {

    let actives = this.tabs.filter((tab) => tab.active);

    if(actives.length === 0) 
      this.select(this.tabs.first);

  }

}
```

And the Tab component code is:

```
export class TabComponent {
  @Input() active: boolean;
  @Input() title: string;
}
```

Comment: You can achieve it by wrapping the content in a `ng-template` that the tabs component instantiates. I'd recommend looking into how Angular Material does it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use regular routing, they can be lazy. Take a look at material tabs, they have support for routing. You can re-implement their API.

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview